# Кодирование и декодирование IP, TCP, UDP, ICMP заоговоков в Asio

Tags: c++, ip, tcp, boost, asio

В этом примере [icmp/ping.cpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/icmp/ping.cpp) при отправке ICMP эхо-запроса кодируется и отправляется только ICMP заголовок, а при получении декодируется сначала IPv4 заголовок, а затем ICMP заголовок. На сколько понял, ICMP очень тесно связан с IP, и по сути является его расширением (поправьте, если не прав). Понятно, что, видимо, Asio берёт на себя формирование IP заголовков. Но сразу возникает пара вопросов:

1. Возможно ли формировать IP заголовки самому для `ip::icmp`, `ip::tcp`, `ip::udp` классов?
2. Возможно ли читать IP и, соответственно, TCP и UDP заголовки, используя `ip::tcp` и `ip::udp`
   классы?

Предположим, я хочу реализовать TCP-пингер, т.к. ICMP не может пинговать порты конкретного устройства, а только само устройство. По идее, мне точно также нужно будет сначала декодировать IP заголовок. Но, имея небольшой опыт в работе с `ip::tcp` классом, я знаю, что можно отправлять HTTP(S) запросы просто как текстовое сообщение, разделяя заголовки `\r\n` и заканчивая их `\r\n\r\n`. Т.е. Asio, в этом случае, берет на себя не только формирование IP заголовка, но и TCP заголовка. Хотя, судя по всему, ICMP заголовок Asio самостоятельно не формирует...

Буду признателен за разъяснение данной неопределенности тем, кто лучше меня разбирается в сетевых технологиях и Boost.Asio. Спасибо.

Comment: Если кто будет искать, то для этих целей в *Asio* есть базовый шаблонный класс *сырых сокетов*: **basic_raw_socket** (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_raw_socket.html)